# MongoDB group by

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

How can I do a query in Mongodb to find the count of entry and exit group by user for a location. the above collection have many locations for which user can enter or exit.

```
{ "ActivityList" : [ 
{ "type" : "entry",
  "timestamp" : Date( 1344473257320 ),
  "user" : { "$ref" : "userProfile",
    "$id" : ObjectId( "4fdeaf6fde26fd298262bb81" ) } }, 
  { "type" : "exit",
  "timestamp" : Date( 1348792321111 ),
  "user" : { "$ref" : "userProfile",
    "$id" : ObjectId( "4fdeaf6fde26fd298262bb81" ) } }, 
{ "type" : "entry",
  "timestamp" : Date( 1348881701129 ),
  "user" : { "$ref" : "userProfile",
    "$id" : ObjectId( "4fdeaf6fde26fd298262bb81" ) } }, 
{ "type" : "exit",
  "timestamp" : Date( 1348942808700 ),
  "user" : { "$ref" : "userProfile",
    "$id" : ObjectId( "4fdeaf6fde26fd298262bb81" ) } }, 
{ "type" : "entry",
  "timestamp" : Date( 1348957400052 ),
  "user" : { "$ref" : "userProfile",
    "$id" : ObjectId( "4fdeaf6fde26fd298262bb81" ) } }, 
{ "type" : "exit",
  "timestamp" : Date( 1349024290729 ),
  "user" : { "$ref" : "userProfile",
    "$id" : ObjectId( "4fdeaf6fde26fd298262bb81" ) } } ],
"Loc" : { "$ref" : "location",
      "$id" : ObjectId( "501cb6d4e7e9a8f958f903c5" ) },
 "_id" : ObjectId( "502308a9e7e91ab176f6708e" ) }
```

I am trying something like this but not successful ,[see here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation)

```
select a,b,sum(c) csum from coll where active=1 group by a,b



db.coll.group(
       {key: { a:true, b:true },
        cond: { active:1 },
        reduce: function(obj,prev) { prev.csum += obj.c; },
        initial: { csum: 0 }
        });
```

Comment: New feature for MongoDB   ------------>  v2.2

Comment: Can you show the code that you tried but wasn't successful?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The document structure you are using (an array of items) will require some manipulation in the `$group()` function that would be easier done with MapReduce or the new [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/) in MongoDB 2.2.

Here's an example using the Aggregation Framework:

```
db.activity.aggregate(

    // Find matching documents first (can take advantage of index)
    { $match : {
        Loc: DBRef("location", ObjectId("501cb6d4e7e9a8f958f903c5"))
    }},

    // Unwind the ActivityList array as a document stream
    { $unwind : "$ActivityList" },

    // Group the stream by activity types for a user
    { $group : {
        _id : "$ActivityList.user",
        activity: { $push: "$ActivityList.type" } 
    }},

    // Unwind the activity types so they can be counted
    { $unwind : "$activity" },

    // Final grouping: count of action (entry or exit) for each user
    { $group : {
        _id : { user: "$_id", action: "$activity" },
        count: { $sum: 1 }
    }}
)
```

Which produces a result similar to:

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : {
                "user" : DBRef("userProfile", ObjectId("4fdeaf6fde26fd298262bb81")),
                "action" : "exit"
            },
            "count" : 6
        },
        {
            "_id" : {
                "user" : DBRef("userProfile", ObjectId("4fdeaf6fde26fd298262bb81")),
                "action" : "entry"
            },
            "count" : 3
        },
        {
            "_id" : {
                "user" : DBRef("userProfile", ObjectId("4fdeaf6fde26fd298262bb82")),
                "action" : "entry"
            },
            "count" : 2
        },
        {
            "_id" : {
                "user" : DBRef("userProfile", ObjectId("4fdeaf6fde26fd298262bb85")),
                "action" : "entry"
            },
            "count" : 1
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Not trolling, but how is this easier than MySQL? Every proponent of mongodb has always told me it's easier to use than MySQL

Comment: @ajacian81 It's easier to scale than MySQL (and other SQL DBs) but writing queries is not necessarily easier (or harder) than other DBs.  Some queries using MapReduce/aggregation are easier to write than the corresponding SQL queries, some harder.  For basic SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE I'd say Mongo's about the same in terms of difficulty writing these queries vs. SQL.

Comment: @Stennie: How to iterate over the same result in javascript?

Comment: @Workonphp: In MongoDB 2.2/2.4 the aggregation results are returned inline in a `result` array in the response document.  If you want to iterate the array in JavaScript you can use array.forEach, eg:`db.collection.aggregate(...).result.forEach(function(doc) { printjson(doc) })` where `printjson()` is whatever you want to do on each result document.  FYI, in the upcoming MongoDB 2.6 release (or the dev/unstable 2.5 releases) the aggregate command will provide a cursor based iterator by default, similar to a normal find().